# Erro ao tentar acessar localhost no wamp server

Tags: wamp

Baixei o Wamp Server 2.5 desse site [aqui](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)
instalei ele normalmente fiz as configurações necessárias como mostrado nas imagens abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

porem como podem ver na imagem meu icone do wamp server só fica vermelho nem laranja ele pelo menos fica já coloquei varias portas diferentes para ver se funciona e nada oque será que pode ser  tento acessar meu localhost e nada quando clico na opção localhost dentro do meu wamp server ele aparece esse erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
 mesmo quando acesso via url nada acontece porque me ajudem

segue  erro quando tento executar via prompt:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Está usando o windows 10?

Comment: nao nao to usando windows 8 amigo

Comment: Tente o seguinte, abra o cmd, e vá navegando até a pasta apach\bin, inicie por la o httpd.exe, veja se vai aparecer algum erro no prompt, não esqueça de ver o log de erros do apache.

Comment: amigo tentei aqui e nada ele aparece um erro

Comment: Apareceu algum erro? no prompt?

Comment: amigo vo ediatr a miha pergunta e vo colocar o erro que ta dando juntamente com os caminhos que fiz do prompt da uma olhada

Comment: Coloca como texto, as imagens estão bloqueadas aqui.

Comment: beleza segue o ero que esta dando : the program can't start becouse libsasl.dll is missing from your computer.

Comment: o caminho que usei foi c:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/bin e executei o httpd.exe

Comment: Essa extensão é do mongoDB? essa dll está na pasta ext? existe o registro dela no php.ini?